# Image upload crud operations in django-restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Im new to django, i want to create API for image upload CRUD in drf.

i have done create and read images , it works but dont know how to update and delete it by using id

**models.py**

```py
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```py
class FileUploadView(ListAPIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = File.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(file_serializer)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(
              file_serializer.data,
              status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        else:
            return Response(
              file_serializer.errors,
              status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

i want to know how update and delete works

Comment: Have you tried to use a ViewSet? Instead of FileUploadView, you can use   `class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer`

Comment: Let me know when you need more help

Comment: problem solved thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @manpikin, by doing this way, we can solve it easly

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = File.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

but in my case there is some hidden code in between so i have done it in this way, i hope this will help some one facing same problem like me

views.py

```py
class FileUploadView(ListAPIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = File.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(file_serializer)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(
                file_serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                file_serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

    def put(self, request):
        imageid = self.request.POST.get('id')
        f_obj = File.objects.filter(id=imageid) #File is my model name
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(f_obj, data=request.data)
        print(file_serializer)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(
                file_serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                file_serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

    def delete(self, request):
        imageid = self.request.POST.get('id')
        f_obj = File.objects.filter(id=imageid) #File is my model name
        if f_obj.exists():
            f_obj.delete()
            return Response(
                {
                    "Status": True,
                    "Message": "image deleted"
                }
            )
```

update and delete will work in this way